# Assistance with adding a record to a table without using the actual data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I need to add a new student record to the Enrollment table without using the actual field. I must "somehow" pull in the data from the Class and Student tables. I may use subqueries but the statement can also be written without the use of subqueries.

I tried writing a statement without a subquery and it failed.

```
insert into enrollment (class_id)  
select class_id where class_name = 'Geometry'  
insert into enrollment (student_id)  
select student_id where first_name 'Michael' and last_name = 'Cronin'  
insert into enrollment (semester)  
values ('Spring 2020');
```

The two tables are below.

**Class**

```
class_id (p)       class_name  
101                Geometry  
102                English  
103                Physics
```

**Student**

```
student_id (p)     first_name       last_name  
500                Robert           Smith  
762                Frank            Carter  
881                Joseph           Evans  
933                Anne             Baker  
999                Michael          Cronin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single insert and specify the columns to be affected and values to be inserted

```
insert into enrollment (class_id, student_id, semester)
select 
  class_id 
 ,(select student_id 
    from  Student  
    where first_name 'Michael' and last_name = 'Cronin')
 ,'Spring 2020'
from class
where class_name = 'Geometry';
```